# How to properly throw nullPointerException?

Tags: java, linked-list

I need to write a method `delete()` that takes an int argument k and deletes the kth element in the linked list, if it exists.  I also want to watch when the list is empty, or k is out of bounds.  If either of those are true, I want to throw a `NullPointerException`.  The code I have so far is below.

```
    public void delete(int k){
      Node current = head;
      for (int i = 0; i < k; i++){
          if(head == null && current.next == null){
              throw new NullPointerException();
              }
          else 
          {
              current = current.next; // Move pointer to k position
          }
      }
      remove(current.item);
      --N;  
  }
```

When I go to execute it with a value that I know will be null, I get the following output:

```
Exception in thread "main" 
java.lang.NullPointerException
at hw4.LinkedList.delete(LinkedList.java:168)
at hw4.LLTest1.main(LLTest1.java:23)
```

However, if I remove the `throw new NullPointerException();` line from my code, I still get that same error message when executing the code with a value that I know will be null.

My question is, am I implementing the `throw new NullPointerException();` command correctly, and if not, how can I fix my implementation of it?

Comment: are you sure that curren´t isn´t null and throws when you access `current.next`?

Comment: I check if head is null in the if statement, and since current equals head, I think if head is null, then current would therefore be null.  At least, that was my logic.

Comment: You might think you want to, but it's not appropriate. Throw an accurate exception (e.g., out of bounds).

Comment: @OmarN Just a tip: if you write `if(current == null && current.next == null)`, it's easier to read what you're trying to do. Another good idea is to include enough detail in the exception message, to help track down problems easily.

Comment: @KevinEsche It isn't but neither is it `null`.

Comment: @biziclop yeah my bad, actually `head == null && current.next == null` is throwing, which is logical. If  `head` is null `current.next` can only throw.

Comment: Throwing a NullPointerException in your code is just confusing when you really have NPEs thrown in your code. If you have an error situation, use IllegalStateException or IllegalArgumentException.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys.  Maybe I am using the wrong type of exception.  Btw, when I wrote `if(current == null && current.next == null)`, I got a message on the side saying "dead code."  That is why I did not use it.

Comment: @OmarN it should be an `||` instead of an `&&`

Comment: @OmarN That was my mistake, I'm sorry. What you really need is `if(current == null || current.next == null)`, and the error message is a very good clue that there's something wrong with the original condition.

Comment: @OmarN Always trust your compiler until it is proven to be in error ;-)

Comment: Gotcha, thanks for the help guys.  I think I am using the wrong exception handling here.  I should be using Index out of bounds.

Comment: Why would you want to throw an exception? That just crashes your program. Instead when your variables are null, create situation where you fill them with something.

Comment: Interesting point.  So what is the reason to throw any exception at all?  Why not just not throw an exception and let the program crash anyway?

Comment: Actually, as I review the code, I think I understand.  If you want to catch the exception to handle it, you have to first throw one.  That is the reason we throw exceptions I believe.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Firstly, you don't typically **throw** a `NullPointerException`.

This is an unchecked exception thrown when referencing a `null` value, which indicates a coding error rather than a recoverable condition.

Secondly, when you're not explicitly throwing the exception in your code, yet seeing it thrown anyway, it's likely that your value for `current` is `null`, hence `current.next` would throw it.

You could try a number of explicit exceptions to throw:

- `IndexOutOfBoundsException`
- `NoSuchElementException`
- `IllegalStateException`
- Etc. etc., or your own custom exception

Comment: @biziclop: There's nothing preventing that.

Comment: If head == null then current == null, hence NPE

Comment: @biziclop can we all remove these comments here?